# communication between backend of website and a python script on a different laptop

Tags: python, flask

communication between a backend of website(flask) and a python script on a different laptop which will then automate something.

Thanks in advance I am looking for something that can transfer info like what website to go to.

Thanks that answered the question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have a look at WebSockets. You could use [socket.io](https://python-socketio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/server.html)

You could also create another backend API on the laptop with the script. Then use post/get requests to get the data needed.

If you need the data only on the script, just a simple get request to the backend api will do.

If you need two-way communication then either using the post requests which cannot be instant or using WebSockets.

Comment: thanks is there a way i can send post's t the backend and vise versa

Comment: @husaynJaffer With socket.io you can use `.emit()` to send data to the server, and `@socket.event` to receive data. You could use `requests` for posting data to the server